# How to convert my output into a suitable table for ANOVA or Kruskwallis testing on SPSS?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, spss, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

Let's say I have asked an individual to classify images according to 3 fruits that he sees : apple, banana and kiwi. Then, I want to assess whether there are significant differences between the frequencies of each classified fruit (there are more instances, this is just an example). I am thinking of using one-way ANOVA or kruskal-wallis test to assess these but my output is the following:

| IMAGE | FRUIT SEEN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana |
| 2 | Kiwi |
| 3 | Apple |
| 4 | Banana |

How do I convert this into SPSS so that I can conduct either ANOVA or Kruskal - wallis test? Does the following below looks okay or am I missing something or am I even using the right statistical test?

| Category | Banana | Kiwi | Apple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Kiwi | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Apple | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Banana | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the question of "whether there are significant differences between the frequencies of each classified fruit" is relevant?  Wouldn't you really want to assess the accuracy of the classification?

Comment: @whuber thank you for your feedback. I did assess the intercoder reliability which achieved a kappa of 0.92 (high agreement) but now thinking about it maybe I just need to stick to that for the report.